# How to get id when the user clicks the list in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo

I am new to openerp. I have a tree data when the user clicks the specific row need to get the employee ID. Here please seen the below image more idea about this,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to show the User logon or the record ID in the `res_users` table?

Standard pattern...

1. Create a new module.
2. Extend the leave requests model to add the column you want (if it isn't already there).
3. Extend the tree view and add the column in.

If the field already exists on the model, you could just update the view XML from the settings menu. Both of these require a certain knowledge of OpenERP though.

Comment: Thanks for reply Adrian. I need to get the employee_id to another window when the user clicks on the list(previous window).

Comment: Hmm, you won't be able to go to a new window when you click on the row, OpenERP will just want to Open  the form view.  But.. if the user is a many2one field, then from the form view they can click on it to go to the user view, or you can add a button to the tree (list) view that triggers an action to go to the new form.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. +1 for this comment.